Text in Word--specifically file paths--gets moved to a new line
How do you prevent long strings from starting their own line?
I frequently use documents where file paths are referenced. Regularly, a file path is longer than the text width of the page. The file path ends up making some lines really short and ugly because Word is breaking the path in an unexpected place. It looks particularly bad when using "justify" for the formatting setting.
If the file path has breaking characters (like a space or hyphen), then the string breaks in a weird spot and the formatting is ugly.
It        looks        like        this        /my/file/path/is/really_kind_of
long/and/it keeps going/version3/computer42/somewhere/in/the/world.txt

If the file path has no non-breaking characters (like if I swap out the hyphens for a "non-breaking" dash), then the entire file path is moved to a new line and the line "breaks" at the end of the width and the rest of the path comes on the line below that.
It                    looks                      like                     this
/my/file/path/is/really_kind_of long/and/it keeps going/version3/computer42/so
mewhere/in/the/world.txt

I'd really like it to do something more like this:
It looks like this /my/file/path/is/really_kind_of long/and/it keeps going/ver
sion3/computer42/somewhere/in/the/world.txt

Does anyone know the secret incantation to make this happen?

Have you tried using a non-breaking space before the long string? Does Keep text together - Microsoft Support answer your question?

Left justify to keep words from being spread out. I know of no way to get the result you desire.

Not very nice, and it won't scale, but you can add a very thin space after every character in the path. e.g., insert space, and use Font->Advanced->Spacing, Condensed by 3pt to make it narrow, then copy/paste after every character in the path.
That's tedious, but not so much with a VBA macro, e.g. select the path and run
Sub addVeryThinSpaces()
Dim i As Long
With Selection.Range
  For i = .Characters.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
    .Characters(i).InsertAfter " "
    .Characters(i + 1).Font.Spacing = -3
  Next
End With    

End Sub
If you want to remove them, select the path (or the whole document, if you know there aren't any other 3pt-condensed spaces), and run, e.g.
Sub removeVeryThinSpaces()
Dim i As Long
''Dim r As Word.Range
With Selection.Range
  For i = .Characters.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
    If (.Characters(i).Text = " ") And (.Characters(i).Font.Spacing = -3) Then
      .Characters(i).Delete
    End If
  Next
End With
End Sub

I leave you to research how to install and run a VBA macro if that is unfamiliar territory.

I was just writing up a similar solution, but using zero-width space (Unicode 200B) instead, and adding just before (or after) every / character. That way, there's no need to bother fiddling with the font properties.

@cnread, yes, I tried the zero-width non joiner, and also the 1/4-m space, but neither of them seemed to work as I hoped when I toggled Show/Hide to Hide. But I wasn't being particularly thorough!
